# Any boilerplate of Backbone+Requirejs+CoffeeScript?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

Recently I'm looking for a well structured boilerplate of Backbone along with Requirejs and CoffeeScript. I've been familiar with Backbone and Requirejs already. But I prefer the CoffeeScript more than the original js. Anyone has a good idrea of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tiny weekend project I did recently called [flickr date fixer](https://github.com/focusaurus/flickr-date-fixer). It's not set up to be used as boilerplate, but it's small enough to serve essentially the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com) is what I want. And your project would help me learn to use it.